# What is meant by a rarer medium?

Tags: waves

[image]

if the red line represents a wire with greater mass and the yellow wire with relatively lower mass.
how do I find the rarer medium in this case, assuming there is no energy loss
???
I read a couple of places and they say: the medium where the wave travels  faster is the rarer medium

But I don't understand why and also its significance?

(assuming wave to be harmonic)

Comment: please dont mind the bad drawing

Comment: “Rarer” means “less dense”.

Comment: how is this related to waves on a string??

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_vibration

Comment: Less well done? Oops, that would be over on Cooking SE...

Answer (score 3):

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_vibration):

> The velocity of propagation of a wave in a string ($v$) is proportional to the square root of the force of tension of the string ($T$) and inversely proportional to the square root of the linear density ($\mu$) of the string: $$v=\sqrt\frac{T}{\mu}$$

This follows from the wave equation governing small vibrations $y(x,t)$ of a taut string, which is

$$\frac{\partial^2 y}{\partial x^2}=\frac{\mu}{T}\frac{\partial^2 y}{\partial t^2}.$$

“Rarer” means “less dense”, which for a string means “smaller $\mu$”.

Answer (score 0):

In this 1D case, rarer medium means the medium where the mass per unit of length is smaller. This is something that we could call 1D density